# drag_indicator is not included with the regular icons in material design

Tags: css, angularjs, fonts, icons, material-design

drag_indicator is not included with the regular icons in material design. Should I somehow add it manually?

Following [this](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) guide I added the icons with the help of the following css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("@{fontPath}/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot"); /* For IE6-8 */
    src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url("@{fontPath}/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"), url("@{fontPath}/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2") format('woff2'), url("@{fontPath}/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff") format('woff'), url("@{fontPath}/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf") format('truetype'), url("@{fontPath}/MaterialIcons-Regular.svg") format('svg');
}

.grey-color {
    color: @grey-color;
}

.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-size: 24px; /* Preferred icon size */
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    /* Support for Firefox. */
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    /* Support for IE. */
    font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

Now I am able to use codes to embed some icons. E.g. the following markup piece works as expected (displays the move_vert icon):

```
<span class="material-icons">
    &#xe5d4;
</span>
```

While the following piece do not work:

```
<span class="material-icons">
    &#xf58e;
</span>
```

It seems that I am not the only one experiencing the issue. [Here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/568) is a similar thread. But it is not clear to what conclusion the thread led. So, the question is still relevant for being posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is included, maybe the problem is that your Material icons lib is downloaded locally (self-host web font) and it is old.

If you use fonts via Google-hosted Fonts, no problems occur.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
       <i class="material-icons">drag_indicator</i>
</body>
</html>
```

Try to re-download Fonts, if it didn't help, you can also download WOFF2 file from the same source that google web hosting provides: [WOFF2](https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v48/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2)
Which included in this link: [https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons](https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material%20Icons)

Comment: Yes, my fonts are old and self hosted. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you know, what is the code for the icon? I mean not the word `drag_indicator`, but a numeric code.